# How can I disable change tracking to prevent spring data from doing dirty checks and tracking changes for read only queries

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way in Spring Data to disable tracking changes (like EntityFramework) when loading an entity with lots of records(Say 100000 records)? I know we can write a view on DB and point an entity to it so. But it looks like over complication as in EntityFramework you can use `AsNoTracking()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Hibernate's [StatelessSession](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html). From the Documentation:

> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor
>   interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement
>   transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do
>   operations cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by
>   a stateless session. Operations performed via a stateless session
>   bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions
>   are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a
>   first-level cache.